# avconv set really slow frame rate

Tags: video, vlc, mplayer, avconv

I have just a couple of images ( 20-40 ) and I want make movie which plays with frame rate 1-2 fps ( i.e. each image should be visible for 0.5-1 second ) ... so the whole movie should take ~20-40 seconds to play. It seem that video generated using avconv with option `-r 1` or `-r 2` does not do this job :-( .

If I generate the movie in this way:

```
avconv -i ./relief_%04d.png -force_fps -r 1 -vf "scale=320:240" test.avi
```

I also tried option `-force_fps` it has no effect

it does strange things:

1. the movie plays just ~2 seconds ( instead of 20-40 seconds )
2. it does not show every images ( just 1-2 )
3. it is like very *laggy*

( and it is also a bit dependent on the player. mplayer do the strange things described above, vlc shows just black screen )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but try specifying the framerate *before* you specify the input file:

```
avconv -r 1 -i ./relief_%04d.png \
   -vf "scale=320:240" \
   test.avi
```

This may be enough to get you moving hopefully, if not there are many more hints on this page:

[Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)

Note especially the method of specifying the framerate twice which would bear some experimentation with in your case.

This is aimed at FFmpeg rather than avconv but should hopefully work with both...

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was it... the order of parameters does matter, and avconv does not inform you about that

Comment: Linux often leaves the safety catch off :)

Answer (score 0):

Use MP4Box.
MP4Box is a MP4 multiplexer. It can import MPEG-4 video, DivX, XviD, 3ivx, h264 etc, audio streams and subtitles into the .mp4 container.

Can be downloaded in http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MP4Box